# A path '....' exists and is a directory but its contents cannot be printed

Tags: python, filesystems

For this code:

```
print(Path('...').exists())
print(Path('...').is_dir())
for x in Path('...').iterdir():
    print(x)
```

The console spits out

```
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PROJECTPATH", line 37, in <module>
    for x in Path('...').iterdir():
  File "C:\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1115, in iterdir
    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '...'
```

If the .exist() and .isdir() both return true for the specified path, then why is there in error when I try to print out the contents of this directory using iterdir?